# ¿Cómo puedo esconder un proceso mientras instalo un paquete?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estoy por realizar un script Bash y no quiero que se vea el proceso en el script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    clear
    echo -ne " instalando Paquete git e vim"
    read input
    pkg install git -y; pkg install vim
    echo " [ LA INSTALCIÓN FUE EXITOSA ]"
done
```

[image: quiero que me salga el proceso oculto]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo esto se aproxima a lo que buscas. Puedes usar el comando wait para espera la ejecucion del comando anterior y comprobar el resultado con la variable $?

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo -ne " instalando Paquete git e vim"
pkg install git vim -y 2&>/dev/null &
PID=$!
wait $PID
RESULT=$?
clear
if [[ $RESULT -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo " [ LA INSTALACION FUE EXITOSA ]"
else
        echo " [ LA INSTALACION FALLO ]"
fi
```

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias  @Juan Pedro

Answer (score 2):

Con el comando Ctrl+Z pausas el proceso y seguido del comando "bg" lo pasas a segundo plano (background).

Answer (score 1):

¡Tu script podrías hacerlo en tan sólo una línea de comandos!

```
pkg install <nombre del paquete> -y &> /dev/null && echo Se instalo || echo Hubo problemas
```

Lo que hago aquí es simplemente redirigir tanto la salida estándar como la salida de errores a `/dev/null` para que no muestre nada en pantalla, luego, el operador `&&` realiza lo que está a continuación si el comando anterior tuvo un código de salida exitoso (igual a 0), de lo contrario, se ejecutará lo seguido del operador `||`.

La ventaja de hacerlo de esta manera es que no ocupas memoria de más, ni variables o condicionales extra, es más, ni siquiera necesitas un script.